# Why does auditd only log `echo` when I use the absolute path?

Tags: auditd

## Info

Running auditd version 2.6.5 on Centos 7.

My rules file contains:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F auid=0 -S execve -k root_action
-a exit,always -F arch=b32 -F auid=0 -S execve -k root_action
```

When I run `which echo`, I get `/usr/bin/echo`.

## Issue

When I run `echo "asd"`, nothing gets logged in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. However, when I run `/usr/bin/echo "asd"` I see an event get logged. Why does it not work without the use of the absolute path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

echo is a shell builtin.  /bin/echo is a binary.

Type `type echo` and `which echo` to see the difference.

When you give it the full path, you are telling it to use the binary rather than the shell builtin.